# Springboot: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My springboot application stopped working after I added a new Jar to my application. With addition of new Jar, I am getting below error:

```
2023-04-20 12:51:26.755  WARN 4732 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'vehicleCapabilitiesExtractor' defined in file [C:\repo\Compare\kbc-core\kbc-core-app\target\classes\com\myApp\new\kbc\core\client\test\testCapabilitiesExtractor.class]: 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'testtestService' defined in file [C:\repo\Compare\kbc-core\kbc-core-app\target\classes\com\myApp\new\kbc\core\test\testvehicle\TesttestService.class]: 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'whiteListService' defined in file [C:\repo\Compare\kbc-core\kbc-core-database\target\classes\com\myApp\new\kbc\database\service\whitelist\WhiteListService.class]:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'whiteListRepository' defined in com.myApp.new.kbc.database.dao.whitelist.WhiteListRepository defined
 in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EntitiesAutoConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.myApp.new.kbc.database.dao.whitelist.WhiteListEntity
```

The application has database module in a separate package and it was working fine.
My application does not have any separate configuration for db. However, the jar which I added has
following configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan({"com.kbc.newApp.${spring.application.id}"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.kbc.newApp.${spring.application.id}"})
class EntitiesAutoConfiguration {
}



@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kbc.newApp.app.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class AslAppApplication {

   @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }
    
    }
```

I tried different combinations of adding  @EntityScan, @EnableJpaRepositories @EntitiesAutoConfiguration in my application too but somehow my entities are not getting recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `com.myApp.new.*` to `EntityScan` and other annotations too. e.g. 
`@EntityScan(basePackages= {"com.myApp.new","com.kbc.newApp"})`

Comment: Our application does not have EntityScan annotation.  EntityScan is part of the Jar which I am newly adding it. I dont have any control over the newly added Jar.

Comment: You can create your own configuration class and add @EntityScan to it

Comment: Can you please share your project structure?

Comment: I added EntityScan but I am still getting same error : "nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type ".